# How to use @selector? to call another method

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to call a method inside my `viewDidLoad` method. How can I do that? I did a fast search and I found `@selector`.  I have never used it before, can any one give me a fast example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need [selector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocSelectors.html) to call a method, you can invoke it directly, e.g. to call someMethod method that takes no parameters on someObject you can do the following:

```
[anObject someMethod];
```

or to call someMethod on current object you can use [self](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/02/08/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html):

```
[self someMethod];
```

If you really need to call a method via selector use performSelector: method (or another of few methods of 'performSelector' family) of NSObject:

```
[anObject performSelector:@selector(someMethod)];
```